# Button hover effect not affecting icon inside button

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to show underline effect on button with font-awesome but I want to affect both text and icon but it affects only text inside button ignoring icon completely (as in example). Is there any way to stretch this underline to icon also?

```css
button {
  color: #333;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="comment-actions" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: start;">

    <button><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Report</button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Save</button>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font awesome `<i>` elements are displayed as `inline-block` by default, which won't be affected by underlines. However if you overwrite the default style and show them as `inline` elements, they will be treated like the text:

```css
button {
  color: #333;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button .fa {
  display: inline;
}

button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="comment-actions" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: start;">
    <button><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Report</button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Save</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that text-decoration doesn't automatically extend to pseudo-elements, which is what the icons are. You can adjust your CSS to cover that.

```css
button {
  color: #333;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
}

button:hover, button:hover :before {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="comment-actions" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: start;">

    <button><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Report</button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Save</button>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your HTML exactly the same and do this:

```css
button:hover, button:hover i {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```